# Validate if property value is false in all objects of array and pick value of property from first three maximum objects of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, key-value

I have an array of objects with properties

```
let array = [{value: "None", selected: false, name: "None"},
{value: "sample utternace", selected: false, name: "sample utternace"},
{value: "sample", selected: false, name: "sample"}]
```

1. I need to validate from these array of objects if "selected" property of all objects is "false".
2. if yes then i need to pick value of property "value" for first three at maximum excluding if "None" value.
3. Maximum 3 values of property "value" should be picked if array size is less than minimum 2 values of property "value" should be pushed to array

Tried:

```
let newArray = [];
let sendValues: boolean;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // validate if all no value selected
    if (array[i].selected === true) {
       sendValues = true;
       break;
       } else {
         break;
       } 
     }                         
      if (sendValues) {                  
                    
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (array[i].value === "None") {
                        newArray.push();
                    } else {
                        newArray.push(array[i].value);
                    }
                }           
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Can you break the question into cases with numbering? It's very hard to understand your question.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]  - your code is not complete. If you change `let sendValues: boolean = false;` to `let sendValues =false;` then there is not even a need for the typescript tag

Comment: What is `if (sendValues) {  }` supposed to do ?

Comment: This is not understandable `If length of array is less and cant pick first three at least i need to pick one or two to minimum.` - less than what?

Comment: I suggest doing some research into the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of the `Array` type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:

```js
let array = [{value: "None", selected: false, name: "None"},
{value: "sample utternace", selected: false, name: "sample utternace"},
{value: "sample", selected: false, name: "sample"}]

console.log(array.every(({selected}) => !selected)); // test all have false
```

Part 2

```js
let array = [{value: "None", selected: false, name: "None"},
{value: "sample utternace", selected: false, name: "sample utternace"},
{value: "sample", selected: false, name: "sample"}]

if (array.every(({selected}) => !selected) ) {
  console.log(array.filter( ({value}) => value !="None")); // filter on value=None
}
```

Part 3

```js
let array = [{value: "None", selected: false, name: "None"},
{value: "sample utterance1", selected: false, name: "sample utterance1"},
{value: "sample utterance2", selected: false, name: "sample utterance2"},
{value: "sample utterance3", selected: false, name: "sample utterance3"},
{value: "sample", selected: false, name: "sample"}]

const getSample = array => {
  let arr = [];
  if (array.every(({ selected }) => !selected)) {
    arr = array.filter( ({ value }) => value != "None")
    if (arr.length >= 3) return arr.slice(0, 3)
  }
  return []; // or some other size
};

console.log(getSample(array))
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan Part2: how i can pick till only first 3 values if array has N number of elements?